# Repeat issue traversing ordered edges in tree query

Tags: gremlin

I have a graph in which a vertex has multiple edges from the same parent. I need to traverse only one of the edges based on the highest property value to create a tree.

I used "order().by" to pick the edge. Works for a one-level query. As soon I try to repeat for a tree there is an error I do not understand:
*"The parent of a reducing barrier can not be repeat()-step: GroupStep([EdgeVertexStep(IN)],[FoldStep])"*

The graph:

```
g.addV("O").property("name",'A').as('A').
  addV("O").property("name",'B').as('B').
  addV("O").property("name",'C').as('C').
  addV("O").property("name",'D').as('D').
  addV("O").property("name",'E').as('E').
  addV("O").property("name",'F').as('F').
  addE("R").property("ver","1").from('A').to('B').
  addE("R").property("ver","2").from('A').to('B').
  addE("R").property("ver","1").from('A').to('C').
  addE("R").property("ver","1").from('B').to('D').
  addE("R").property("ver","1").from('B').to('F')
```

I wish to extract a tree like:

```
A
  B (ver=2)
    D (ver=1)
    F (ver=1)
  C (ver=1)
```

My traverse query with he repeat issue:

```
g.V().has('name','A').
  repeat(
    outE('R').group().by(inV()).
    select(values).unfold().
    local(unfold().order().by('ver', desc).limit(1).inV())).
  times(3).
  emit().tree().toList()
```

Result: "The parent of a reducing barrier can not be repeat()-step: GroupStep([EdgeVertexStep(IN)],[FoldStep])"

On Gremlify: https://gremlify.com/r3ubmv3gt8/4

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the you cannot use `group` inside of a `repeat` loop in this way (when used with `emit`), unless you use the side effect form, where `group` is given a label such as `group('x')`. You will need to refactor your query taking that into account.

Perhaps, something along these lines:

```java
gremlin>   g.V().has('name','A').
......1>         repeat(map(outE('R').
......2>                    order().
......3>                      by('ver',desc).
......4>                    limit(1).
......5>                    inV())).
......6>         times(3).
......7>         emit().tree()

==>[v[61415]:[v[61417]:[v[61421]:[]]]]
```

Alternatively, if you know the maximum depth, you can remove `emit` and probably `tree` and just use `path`

```java
gremlin>   g.V().has('name','A').
......1>         repeat(flatMap(outE('R').
......2>                    order().
......3>                      by('ver',desc).
......4>                    limit(1).
......5>                    inV())).
......6>         times(2).
......7>         path()

==>[v[61415],v[61417],v[61421]]
```

Lastly, if the depth is unknown but you want to set an upper bound you can slightly change the termination condition:

```java
gremlin>   g.V().has('name','A').
......1>         repeat(flatMap(outE('R').
......2>                    order().
......3>                      by('ver',desc).
......4>                    limit(1).
......5>                    inV())).
......6>         until(__.not(out('R')).or().loops().is(3)).
......7>         path()

==>[v[61415],v[61417],v[61421]]
```

**UPDATED 2022-01-03** to add:

Based on the additional information provided in the comments and updated question, I am adding an additional example. Rather than return a `tree` this query returns a new `subgraph` that represents the structure traversed with only the highest version edge between any two adjacent vertices present. I used the Gremlin Console to demonstrate that it works.

```java
gremlin> g.V().has('name','A').
......1>   repeat(outE('R').
......2>          group('x').
......3>            by(loops()).
......4>            by(group().
......5>                 by(inV()).
......6>                 by(order().by('ver',desc).limit(1))).inV()).
......7>   until(__.not(out())).
......8>   cap('x').unfold().select(values).unfold().select(values).subgraph('s').cap('s')   

==>tinkergraph[vertices:5 edges:4]
```

We can create a new `traversal` for this `subgraph` and explore it:

```java
gremlin> g2=g.V().has('name','A').
......1>   repeat(outE('R').
......2>          group('x').
......3>            by(loops()).
......4>            by(group().
......5>                 by(inV()).
......6>                 by(order().by('ver',desc).limit(1))).inV()).
......7>   until(__.not(out())).
......8>   cap('x').unfold().select(values).unfold().select(values).subgraph('s').cap('s').next();[]

==>tinkergraph[vertices:5 edges:4]

gremlin> g3=g2.traversal()    


gremlin> g3.V().outE().inV().path().by('name').by('ver')
==>[A,2,B]
==>[A,1,C]
==>[B,1,F]
==>[B,1,D]


gremlin> g3.V().has('name','A').repeat(outE('R').inV()).until(__.not(out())).path().by('name').by('ver')
==>[A,1,C]
==>[A,2,B,1,F]
==>[A,2,B,1,D]
```

**FURTHER UPDATED**
Right after I posted that last update, I realized a different approach using `flatMap` might do the trick

```java
gremlin> g.V().has('name','A').
......1>       repeat(
......2>         flatMap(
......3>           out().
......4>           dedup().
......5>           local(
......6>             inE().
......7>             order().
......8>               by('ver',desc).
......9>               limit(1))).
.....10>         inV()).
.....11>         until(__.not(out())).
.....12>         path().
.....13>           by('name').
.....14>           by('ver')   

==>[A,1,C]
==>[A,2,B,1,F]
==>[A,2,B,1,D]
```

and to produce a `tree`

```java
gremlin> g.V().has('name','A').
......1>       repeat(
......2>         flatMap(
......3>           out().
......4>           dedup().
......5>           local(
......6>             inE().
......7>             order().
......8>               by('ver',desc).
......9>               limit(1))).
.....10>         inV()).
.....11>         until(__.not(out())).tree()
   
==>[v[0]:[e[13][0-R->2]:[v[2]:[e[16][2-R->10]:[v[10]:[]],e[15][2-R->6]:[v[6]:[]]]],e[14][0-R->4]:[v[4]:[]]]]
```

Comment: Kelvin, Thank you for the asnwer! Though my post is not clear on the outcome of my query. I'm updating it.

Comment: Kelvin, suggestions 2 and 3 do not produce a tree. I tried the first suggestion which remove the issue but does not output the edges from which I need the data in the tree. I appreciate your help.

Comment: OK I'll read the updated question and see what tweaks are needed to my answer in response

Comment: I added to the answer, I found it easier to create a new subgraph rather than a tree - I hope this gives you enough pointers.

Comment: I also added another option. This can be used to yield a `tree`

Comment: Kelvin, thank you so much! Both subgraph, path, and tree are going to be useful. I knew was possible, but I'm not there yet. I will slowly digest each one example. Thank you again.